# Viable ways for interacting with SOAP webservices from Apex

Tags: soap

The current support for interacting with SOAP webservice in Apex is far from ideal:

1. The provided tool on the platform doesn't work in a number of well-known cases
2. An alternative tool advised in forums it's based on .NET and the installers provided work only on Windows (and still doesn't work for us)
3. The https://github.com/forcedotcom/WSDL2Apex tool doesn't pass its tests when building it

How are people doing "these days" integration with SOAP webservices? We will most likely:

1. Build the request by replacing strings in a template (a la Visualforce technique)
2. Parse the response through XPath

Are there better solutions? For example, could one use more mature tools in the Java space and convert the code to Apex simply?

Comment: You mention an alternative tool, which is almost certainly the FuseIT version of WSDL2Apex I work on. Can you share details of your WSDL and what isn't working as expected?

Comment: we nave some duplicate names so dire generation fails. and we do non use microsoft windows

Comment: If you can share the WSDL I'll see what can be done from the generation point of view. Ideally they should be separated via the namespace. Also, there is a web based version of the FuseIT Wsdl2Apex tool to work for any OS.

Comment: sure, it's quite a large wsdl. Can you provide a link to the fuseIt wsdl2apex online and a contact email?

Comment: The download email for the [FuseIT SFDC Explorer](http://fuseit.com/contact/downloads/fuseit-sfdc-explorer/) includes the link to the online version. It's not as fully featured as the Windows version, but it can do most WSDLs. You can find the support contact [email addresses on the site](http://fuseit.com/contact/support/) or via [my blog](https://www.blogger.com/profile/14095711104515084650).

Answer (score 3):

It's more troublesome to write your own XML or, stated differently, it's too easy to screw up and run into edge cases where you accidentally mess up during XML encoding when you use plain strings as merge templates.

Besides the OOTB WSDL2Apex, consider [WSDL2Apex](https://github.com/forcedotcom/WSDL2Apex) instead. The open source version has better support for WSDLs, and more importantly, is open source, meaning you can extend it to include the features you need.

There's a nice post titled "[When “Generate from WSDL” fails – hand-coding web service calls](https://force201.wordpress.com/2010/05/20/when-generate-from-wsdl-fails-hand-coding-web-service-calls/)" that demonstrates the correct way to generate your XML if you need to.

I've had quite a bit of success by simply using Eclipse's WSDL builder to import a WSDL that's not supported, remove or tweak elements, save the resulting changes, and then apply WSDL2Apex.

[This question and answer](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008vMRIAY) on the Developer Forums addresses an alternative way to deal with the problem, which I'll quote here:

> Hi,
>
> I had to deal with an WSDL with external schemas which they also
> import other schemas. It was a mess at first but the solution was
> easier than I thought.
>
> 1. Open the WSDL with a text editor
> 2. Inside `<wsdl:types>` (below the last `<schema>`) paste each referenced .xsd file content. Paste only `<schema></schema>`
> 3. Once all schemas are in the WSDL then comment all `<xsd:import>` using `<!-- -->`. They are no longer needed.
> 4. Save and you are ready to go.
>
> Some of my classes returned compiling errors because of Exception classes that must extend the
> Salesforce Exception class. So copy the generated class, correct it
> into a text editor and then created manually as after clicking "Done",
> changes are not reprocessed.
>
> Regards,
>
> Sebastian

Quoted from [SebaOrtiz](https://dfc-org-production.force.com/forums/ForumsProfile?communityId=09aF00000004HMG&userId=005F0000003Fe3w)

I realize that this sounds complicated, but 9 out of 10 times, it's usually painless. I've done it myself a few times, and once you get the knack of it, it's usually not too bad. I usually save these WSDL files as static resources in case I need to tweak them later (make sure you document where they're stored).

Whatever you do, consider yourself advised that writing your own XML is generally a Bad Thing, and consider using a method that's less likely to break in amusing and bizarre ways.

Comment: WSDL2Apex master branch fails to compile, I got 12 test failures...

Comment: @Edmondo1984 Curious. I know it hasn't been updated in a while, but let me see if I can get it ticking...

Answer (score 0):

> An alternative tool advised in forums it's based on .NET and the installers provided work only on Windows (and still doesn't work for us)

I'm assuming this is the [FuseIT SFDC Explorer](http://www.fuseit.com/explorer) version of WSDL2Apex. It's true that it is .NET only at this stage (unless you use the web based version). All my tooling and OS's and Windows based, so I'm unable to support other operating systems.

---

With regards to the specific problem with your WSDL, it is a bit of an edge case in the world of special snowflakes that are WSDLs (as in, there are so many edge cases that are still "valid" WSDLs that it's near impossible to account for them all).

The interesting part of the WSDL you provided is around the schema definitions under the `wsdl:types` element. There are multiple occurrences of schema with the same namespace being defined.

E.g. Note that both of these have identical `targetNamespace` attributes.

> <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:dynamic_application_framework="http://www.visual-rules.com/vrpath/Dynamic%20Application%20Framework/" xmlns:standard_types="http://www.bosch-si.com/daf/v1_13/vr-standard-types" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified" **targetNamespace="http://www.visual-rules.com/vrpath/Dynamic%20Application%20Framework/"**>
>
> <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.visual-rules.com/vrpath/Dynamic%20Application%20Framework/" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" **targetNamespace="http://www.visual-rules.com/vrpath/Dynamic%20Application%20Framework/"**/>

I'm not saying it's wrong, but it certainly isn't a common occurrence in WSDLs.

Why is this duplication problematic? Each schema namespace gets mapped into a corresponding Apex class. The code that was doing the mapping was failing to handle the repeated mapping. The next release of the FuseIT tooling will allow for this scenario.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, the generated XML is wrong though :( I am unable to invoke the webservice

Comment: @Edmondo1984 can you provide specific details around how the generated XML isn't working? Are you getting an error message, and if so what is it?

Comment: It is not passing validation on the web service (while the one that I generate through SoapUI) does. In particular, it seems that even if I change the last argument to 'true" for the apex_schema_type_info , some nodes are not qualified (requestData, in particular)