# Multiple namespaces when invoking SOAP webservice

Tags: soap, wsdl2apex

I have a SOAP webservice whose body should contain different namespaces, however the APEX generated classes with FuseIT do not include namespaces when serialized to XML.

I'd like to do the following:

1. Include additional bindings of prefix-to-namespaces at the envelope level (i.e.`<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cen="http://wwww.some.urls/blah"">`)
2. I'd like to have the xml been serialized with the prefix `<cen:Item1>a</cen:Item1>`

I wasn't able to find much documentation, what's the riht way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Wsdl2Apex and the corresponding [`WebServiceCallout.invoke`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_WebServiceCallout.htm) methods won't be able to handle this for you.

To get the level of control you want will require manually building the XML in Apex for the SOAP request.

The FuseIT version of WSDL2Apex can generate the Apex for you. It won't be complete, but it would give you a strong starting point. However, because of the oddities in your WSDL support for this won't be publicly available until the next release is made. Failing that you could fall back to the tips from your previous question - [Viable ways for interacting with SOAP webservices from Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/173033/102)

Comment: It seems that even the FuseIT version generates classes that are not suitable, and even after changing them the XML is still not the one that a "standard" tool like soap UI generates. Are there libraries to manually build the XML ? Templating ?

Comment: The FuseIT tool is still ultimately limited to what WebServiceCallout.invoke supports in Apex. As that is a Salesforce provided method there isn't much that can be done to improve the situation. As I mentioned, the FuseIT tooling can generate a starting point for you in Apex to manually create the SOAP envelopes. This will give you much greater freedom to modify it as required. However, I can't help you with this right now as it requires access to the latest unreleased build.

Comment: Good point. How do you manually create the envelopes in Apex?

Comment: Directly against the XML DOM - [Reading and Writing XML Using the DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_xml_dom.htm)

Comment: oh and I imagine you suggest the future version of FuseIt will actually work like a code generator so you can customize it?

Comment: It does currently do so, just not for your particular WSDL due to some of the schema targetNamespace oddities.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58711/discussion-between-edmondo1984-and-daniel-ballinger).